# Why the overridden method should be public in this program?

Tags: java, interface, public, access-specifier

```
import java.util.*;
interface AdvancedArithmetic{
  int divisor_sum(int n);
}
class MyCalculator implements AdvancedArithmetic
{
    int sum=0;
    int divisor_sum(int n)  //Why this method should be public?
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            if(n%i==0)
            sum=sum+i;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

why the method inside class MyCalculator should be public?
It shows an error like

error: divisor_sum(int) in MyCalculator cannot implement divisor_sum(int) in AdvancedArithmetic
    int divisor_sum(int n)
        ^
  attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public
1 error

Comment: All methods on interfaces (before Java 9) are public, whether you declare them as such or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int divisor_sum(int n)` implements an interface method. Interface methods have `public` access (even if you don't specify it explicitly), so you cannot reduce the visibility of the method in the implementing class.

Consider the following:

```
MyCalculator mc = new MyCalculator();
AdvancedArithmetic aa = mc;
```

If you don't give `divisor_sum()` method in `MyCalculator` class a `public` access level, you won't be able to call it via the class reference (`mc.divisor_sum(4)`), but you would be able to call it via the interface reference (`aa.divisor_sum(4)`). This makes no sense, and therefore not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Consider programming against interfaces.
Your interface guarantees there is a method `divisor_sum(int n)` with `public` as (default) access modifier.

Now, imagine this:

```
public void doSomething(AdvancedArithmetic implementation) {
    int test = implementation.divisor_sum(5);
    // continue
}
```

If Java would allow a(ny) implementation of this `interface` to put it's `access modifier` of the method as more narrow than the one of the `interface`, this would lead to serious problems and breaking software, since the implementation is not following the contract of the `interface`.